# If there is no reporting verb, would you still use comma in these constructions?

Tags: grammar, commas, colons, dialogue

Usually, after a reporting verb, there is bound to be a comma, but what if the constructions are as follow:

**As if waiting for me to say that one sentence, Cornelia followed up with a request, “Welp, there’s one thing you can help me with.”**

In this example, there is no reporting verb, but with "followed up with a request" it sounds more correct to my ears to add a comma.

**“Ah, um, how do I say this?” Scratching the back of my head, I blurted out the content of my mind: “You sure are pretty today.”**

Looking at this example, "blurted out" is a reporting verb, and therefore, is accompanied with a comma, but because there's an additional "the content of my mind," I think that colon is better.

Still, are these two constructions even grammatically correct?

Comment: Personally, I would use a full stop (period) and treat the speech as a new sentence.

Comment: Not a comma. This is one of the few places I'd retain the colon. // It's confusing to call a verb used in a speech tag (_John said / whispered /groaned ... ; asked Jill_ ...) a reporting verb as this is not reported (indirect) speech. 'Quote/quotative verb' is more felicitous for the usage. //// Note also that speech tags before a quote may be followed by a comma **or** colon **or** (increasingly commonly) zero punctuation. All are considered acceptable per se, though individual sentences may well be better using one or other of the options.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the grammar. But is _grammar_ really what you're asking about? Your choice of punctuation in these examples also seems fine.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the input.
@EdwinAshworth I see. colon does work best here, huh.